# How to insert case insensitive data in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, case-sensitive

I have one table ta1.
In this table, I have already inserted one record **item1**(key), val1(nonKey).
Now I want these records to be case **insensitive**.
i.e. if I want to insert **ITem1**,val2, then I want sqlite to give **constraint error**.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Also, I want only this particular table to contain case insensitive records. Not any other tables in the same database.
Is there any special kind of insert statement to get this result?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `UNIQUE` index on the column with a `NOCASE` collation.

Comment: Here's a working bit of SQLite code based on this answer: http://ideone.com/kTf8k